# Is there a safe way to hold on to a reference to a Go variable from C code using CGo?

Tags: garbage-collection, go, cgo

When using CGo to interface C code with Go, if I keep a reference to a Go variable on the C side, do I run the risk of that object being freed by the garbage collector or will the GC see the pointer in the variables managed by the C side?

To illustrate what I'm asking, consider the following sample program:

Go code:

```
package main

/*
typedef struct _Foo Foo;
Foo *foo_new(void);
void foo_send(Foo *foo, int x);
int foo_recv(Foo *foo);
*/
import "C"

//export makeChannel
func makeChannel() chan int {
    return make(chan int, 1)
}

//export sendInt
func sendInt(ch chan int, x int) {
    ch <- x
}

//export recvInt
func recvInt(ch chan int) int {
    return <-ch
}

func main() {
    foo := C.foo_new()
    C.foo_send(foo, 42)
    println(C.foo_recv(foo))
}
```

C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "_cgo_export.h"

struct _Foo {
    GoChan ch;
};

Foo *foo_new(void) {
    Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->ch = makeChannel();
    return foo;
}

void foo_send(Foo *foo, int x) {
    sendInt(foo->ch, x);
}

int foo_recv(Foo *foo) {
    return recvInt(foo->ch);
}
```

Do I run the risk of `foo->ch` being freed by the garbage collector between the `foo_new` and `foo_send` calls?  If so, is there a way to pin the Go variable from the C side to prevent it from being freed while I hold a reference to it?

Comment: Seems like there isn't a way to prevent Go's garbage collector other than turning it off. http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo says `Memory allocations made by C code are not known to Go's memory manager.` so I would assume that you need to copy the Go value to a C variable if you want to keep a reference to it.

Comment: That part of the blog article just seems to be saying that memory allocated in C won't be freed by Go's GC, which is not what I'm asking about: rather than asking about the lifetime of the `Foo` structure, I'm wondering what the lifetime of the channel I've stored a pointer to.  Copying the variable isn't an option for things like channels (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [gmp CGo example](http://golang.org/misc/cgo/gmp/gmp.go?s=3086:3757#L87) :

> Garbage collection is the big problem.  It is fine for the Go world to
>   have pointers into the C world and to free those pointers when they
>   are no longer needed.  To help, the Go code can define Go objects
>   holding the C pointers and use runtime.SetFinalizer on those Go objects.
>
> It is much more difficult for the C world to have pointers into the Go
>   world, because the Go garbage collector is unaware of the memory
>   allocated by C.  The most important consideration is not to
>   constrain future implementations, so the rule is that Go code can
>   hand a Go pointer to C code but must separately arrange for
>   Go to hang on to a reference to the pointer until C is done with it.

So I'm not sure if you can pin the variable from the C side, but you may be able to control the garbage collection of the variable from the Go side by using the [`runtime.SetFinalizer`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer) function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or: live Go data must always be referenced from the Go heap, because that's all that the GC will scan. Sometimes, to achieve that, your C can call a Go function to do its allocations of reference-holding types. (After all, as long as all your references are in the Go heap, you're fine.) Other times the reference comes from malloc-allocated memory, so you have to write malloc/free wrappers or something to artificially create a references to the Go object from elsewhere in Go-land. For example, those wrappers might be Go functions that add/remove entries in a `map[uintptr]interface{}`.

Comment: Thanks.  I've settled for managing a map of the channels on the Go side: adding to the map when I want to store them on the C side, and removing them from the map when I want to release them on the C side.

Comment: How do you garbage collect the variable manually after turning off GC on a variable?